# Increasing line break in latex beamer

Tags: beamer, line-spacing, line

[image]

As you can see in the image, the line break with \ \ does not have any space between the two texts. On the other hand, the \newline command makes a very big jump.
Is it possible to give the line break more space with \ \ ?

Comment: please show code as text not as an image. the `\newline`at teh end of a paragraph is in error and presumably gives warnings? `\\ `gives a standard line break, as you would have between lines of a paragraph, If it's a new paragraph normally you would leave a blank line in the source, if you need an extra space at teh linebreak for some reason then `\\[10pt]`

Comment: thanks! it is works!